# ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract error when using Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to learn Solidity for the first time by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXa_Y-17Oj4) tutorial.

It's a basic app where you can buy tickets.

So the code is like the following,

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

uint256 constant TOTAL_TICKETS = 10;

contract Tickets {
    address public owner = msg.sender;

    struct Ticket {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 price;
        address owner;
    }

    Ticket[TOTAL_TICKETS] public tickets;
    
    constructor(){
       for(uint256 i = 0; i <= TOTAL_TICKETS ; i++){
        tickets[i].id = i+1;
        tickets[i].price = 1e17;
        tickets[i].owner = address(0x0);
    }
    }

    function buyTicket(uint256 _ID) external payable {

        require(_ID < TOTAL_TICKETS);
        require(_ID > 0);
        require(tickets[_ID-1].owner ==  address(0x0) );
        require(msg.value>tickets[_ID-1].price);

        tickets[_ID-1].owner = msg.sender;

        
    }
}
```

It's showing the following errors,

```
D:\Apps\tickets-dapp>truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Tickets.sol

    /D/Apps/../Tickets.sol:4:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
    uint256 constant TOTAL_TICKETS = 10;
    ^-----^
    
    Compilation failed. See above.
    Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
    Node v16.13.2
```

This is kinda confusing. So what am I doing wrong... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting solidity version <0.8.0 with your `pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;`, you cannot define constants outside of the contract scope.

In this case, you definitely don't need that, so move your constant declaration inside the contract and it'll compile just fine.

Comment: Also, constant has already been deprecated, so it should be removed.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais Can you provide the link stating constant is deprecated? Looking into latest solidity docs doesn't say anything about it

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.17

Comment: But that talks about function modifier `constant` being deprecated in favour of `view` and `pure`. Constant in this example is totally different mechanism. https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html?highlight=constant#constant

Comment: Indeed, you are right.